# How to disable split-screen when opening the app from Edge panels on Samsung Android 12?

Tags: samsung, multi-window

I have a Samsung A53 running with Android 12 and OneUI 4.1.

When I open an application from the Edge panels, it always opens in split-screen / multi-window, if the app has a split-screen layout (such as Google Maps or WhatsApp).

I find this behaviour intensely annoying, but cannot find a way around it - searching the settings yielded a toggle in Advanced - Labs to enable this for *all* apps, but this is obviously the exact opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

An online article mentioned an app named "Samsung multiwindow toggle" where this can be disabled, however I haven't been able to find it in the Play Store. I've also looked through similar questions here, but they were mostly quite old and related to different software versions, with settings that I don't have.

So, what can be done to get rid of this "feature"?

Comment: Have you tried the Samsung AppStore? It usually carries all Samsung-specific apps its developers push to devices. Unless this is a third-party Samsung app? https://www.samsung.com/us/apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings can be changed from the Edge panels' settings directly (not Android settings):

1. Open Edge panels by swiping it
2. Press the hamburger menu (3 horizontal bars)
3. Select "Edit"
4. Press the kebab menu (3 vertical dots)
5. There are 2 options for "Open in split screen view"

   - Touch and hold
   - Tap